# Function Pointers

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I was going through an [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7150/Member-Function-Pointers-and-the-Fastest-Possible) by Don Clugston on Codeproject. It is a beautiful article and is quite famous. In the following code snippet, I found a particular notion very difficult to comprehend:

```
class A {
 public:
       virtual int Afunc() { return 2; };
};

class B {
 public: 
      int Bfunc() { return 3; };
};

// C is a single inheritance class, derives only from A
class C: public A {
 public: 
     int Cfunc() { return 4; };
};

// D uses multiple inheritance
class D: public A, public B {
 public: 
    int Dfunc() { return 5; };
};
```

The snippet is followed by the following paragraph:

> Suppose we create a member function pointer for class C. In this
>   example, Afunc and Cfunc are both member functions of C, so our member
>   function pointer is allowed to point to Afunc or Cfunc. ***But Afunc
>   needs a this pointer that points to C::A (which I'll call Athis),
>   while Cfunc needs a this pointer that points to C (which I'll call
>   Cthis).*** Compiler writers deal with this situation by a trick: they
>   ensure that A is physically stored at the start of C. This means that
>   Athis == Cthis. We only have one this to worry about, and all's well
>   with the world.

The one and the only thing I want to understand is the line in BOLD and ITALICS in the above paragraph.

I do not fully comprehend **Afunc needs a pointer to C::A** while **Cfunc needs a pointer to C** is quite natural.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By calling a member function in C++, what internally happens is that the instance is passed as a hidden first argument (note that this behaviour is strictly implementation-defined behaviour, though. The C++ standard has nothing to say on this topic, it’s just a very common way of implementing it):

```
x.f(y); // is treated internally as:
f(&x, y);
```

This first argument is then available via the `this` pointer.

now, `Afunc` in the example above *internally* has the signature `void Afunc(A* const this)` while `CFunc` has the internal signature `void CFunc(C* const this)`.

Note that the argument types in both cases are different, so when you call the functions on the same object, a different pointer has to be passed. C++ solves this by defining an implicit conversion from any derived object to its base object. That is, in the following code:

```
C* pc = something;
pc->Afunc();
```

This code is treated internally similar to the following (pseudo-code):

```
C* pc = something;
Afunc(static_cast<A*>(pc));
```

This cast is, for single-inheritance, a no-operation (i.e. it can just be removed) through the trick mentioned in the quote: the `C` object and its parent `A` object are stored at the same physical address. An object of type `C` which is stored at an address `x` in memory is physically laid out in such a way that its parent object of type `A` is *also* stored at the address `x`, and is followed by all other members that `C` may have (but in your case it has no members, and `sizeof(C) == sizeof(A)`).

Comment: Could you please rephrase the last sentence?

Comment: @msiyer I’ve tried adding more information, hopefully this is a bit clearer.

Comment: This is a great explanation. I am a Mechanical Engineering graduate and thus, have not taken any CS courses. I am, now, doing it on my own. Learning all that is required to have a solid footing in Compiler design and construction. With answers like these, one may not really miss CS formal education much. Thank you Konrad.

Comment: @msiyer Don’t be so sure. I have a formal education in CS (well, partly, I’m a bioinformatician). Nothing in this answer comes from my CS courses, it’a all self-taught. Most courses (even on compiler design) are fairly theoretical, and even the practical ones that let you build your own compiler probably won’t touch on the implementation of inheritance due to lack of time.